# Finding two list in a dictionary with the most distinct values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a dictionary with a form key:list where key is a name of a student and list is a list of every proffesor of theirs. I need to find two keys(students) with the most distinct values(teachers) in their lists. So basically I need to find the largest intersection.
This is the dictionary I need to work with: https://github.com/kXtof/python3learningprojects/blob/main/find_intersect_of_two_lists/dict_student_teacher
If there is more than one pair with the same amount of dictinct teachers, I can choose which pair I will print.

Comment: What did you expect to be outputed from your program?

Comment: Two names of students(key) with the most distinct values. Basically two keys with the largest intersect.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> max(itertools.combinations(d, 2),
        key=lambda p: len(set(d[p[0]]) & set(d[p[1]])))
('WMXZFQJGJT', 'SMELGPEIOP')
```